# Firebase Appcheck and RecaptchaV3 Provider

Tags: firebase, recaptcha-v3, firebase-app-check

I'm wondering if someone can explain the overlap between Firebase AppCheck and Recaptchav3. I have a public web application with AppCheck enabled and configured to use the Recaptchav3 provider. An integral part of using Recaptcha however is verifying the client's score to determine whether or not to deny the request. AppCheck does it's job in my Firebase function by providing attestation based on referrer, however, I haven't found a way to retrieve the Recaptcha score.

I've tried retrieving the AppCheck token from the X-Firebase-AppCheck header and submitting it to the Recaptcha service for verification, but that returns an invalid user response error.

So my question is: is it possible to retrieve the Recaptcha score from the callable function context? If not, how is this case normally addressed?

I've manually included the Recaptcha script and retrieved the token on the client side which works, but that amounts to Recaptcha being added twice (first with AppCheck and second from a manual inclusion), which doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1):

I've spoken to Firebase support and it seems that it is not possible to retrieve the Recaptchav3 score from AppCheck. So the only solution is to retrieve it on the client-side as you would in a typical Recaptcha config, and submit it along with the request to your backend. The process to verify the Recaptcha token and retrieve the score once received at the backend remains the same.

So at the moment, the only value AppCheck on the web provides is automatic referrer verification.